# Renaming Sequentially Named Files with Date Embedded

Tags: linux, command-line-interface, rename, archlinux, file-management

## The Situation:

I have hundreds of zip files with an arbitrary date/time mixed into its name (`4-6-2021 12-34-09 AM.zip`). I need to get all of these files in order such that (0.zip, 1.zip 2.zip etc) with in a Linux cli system.

### What I've tried:

I've tried `ls -tr | while read i; do n=$((n+1)); mv -- "$i" "$(printf '%03d' "$n").zip"; done` which almost does what I want but still seems to be out of order (I think its taking the order of when the file was created rather than the filename (which is what I need)).

If I can get this done, my next step would be to rename the file (yes a single file) in each zip to the name of the zip file. I'm not sure how I'd go about this either.

### tl;dr

I have these files named with a weird date system. I need the date to be in order and renamed sequentially like `0.zip 1.zip 2.zip etc`. It's 3:00 AM and I don't know why I'm up still trying to solve this and I have no idea how I'll rename the files in the zips to that sequential number (read above for more detail on this).

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GNU awk is an option here, redirecting the result of the file listing back into awk:

```
awk '{ 
        fil=$0;                                          # Set a variable fil to the line
        gsub("-"," ",$1);                                # Replace "-" for " " in the first space delimited field
        split($1,map," ");                               # Split the first field into the array map, using " " as the delimiter
        if (length(map[1])==1) { 
          map[1]="0"map[1]                               # If the length of the day is 1, pad out with "0"
        };
        if (length(map[2])==1) { 
          map[2]="0"map[2]                               # Do the same for month
        }
        $1=map[1]" "map[2]" "map[3];                     # Rebuilt first field based on array values
        gsub("-"," ",$2);                                # Change "-" for " " in time
        map1[mktime($1" "$2)]=fil                        # Get epoch format of date/time using mktime function and use this as an index for array map1 with the original line (fil) as the value
     } 
 END { 
        PROCINFO["sorted_in"]="@ind_num_asc";            # At the end of processing, set the array sorting to index number ascending
        cnt=0;                                           # Initialise a cnt variable
        for (i in map1) { 
           print "mv \""map1[i]"\" \""cnt".zip\"";       # Loop through map1 array printing values and using these values along with cnt to generate and print move command
           cnt++ 
        } 
      }' <(for fil in *AM.zip;do echo $fil;done)
```

Once you are happy with the way the print command are printed, pipe the result into bash and so:

```
awk '{ fil=$0;gsub("-"," ",$1);split($1,map," ");if (length(map[1])==1) { map[1]="0"map[1] };if (length(map[2])==1) { map[2]="0"map[2] }$1=map[1]" "map[2]" "map[3];gsub("-"," ",$2);map1[mktime($1" "$2)]=fil} END { PROCINFO["sorted_in"]="@ind_num_asc";cnt=0;for (i in map1) { print "mv \""map1[i]"\" \""cnt".zip\"";cnt++ } }' <(for fil in *AM.zip;do echo $fil;done) | bash
```

Comment: This works! Thank you! Do you happen to know of a way I can name the single file in these zip files to the name of the zip file (like in `0.zip` the jpg in the zip needs to be extracted to be name `0.jpg`)? If not that's all ok, I'll just make a new question thread.

Comment: I got really close `for f in *.zip; do unzip -p '$f' > "tmp/${f%}.jpg"; done` Its just not naming the file correctly.

Comment: Try for f in *.zip; do unzip -p '$f' > "tmp/${f%.zip}.jpg